# how to create a field for each row and append some text to it in each level of transformation

Tags: ssis, etl

I am using SSIS for transfer some data from a database to another database.

There is a logic that I need to check some conditions and each condition has an error message. Based on the requirement, there should be a column that error text should be appended to it.

I tried to create a column in "Derived Column" and then assign my error text to it.

For the second case, I created a new column in "Derived Column" and the added previous column with the new next created the second column and until the end for other cases.

Now the problem is it is not functioning well and I have .

**I want to know what is the best solution to add a new line of text to a column in SSIS.**

The pseudocode should be as below:

```
String error_text = "";

if logic 1 failed then error_text+= "error1"
if logic 2 failed then error_text+= "error2"
if logic 3 failed then error_text+= "error3"
```

my database is Oracle and I am using OLEDB connection.

Comment: I think you worked out the logic in a more .NET way and could easily incorporate a script task to build that error column.

Comment: If you want to do it in a derived column, I would recommend something like this... 1 derived column object that does all your tests Error1 = test ? "Error1":"" and so on. Then add a 2nd derived column object and Concatenate the error columns.

Comment: @KeithL: thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

- Create a new column for each validation on a derived column task. This should keep the expressions simple and easy to track. Generate another derived column task after the previous one that joins all possible errors together, which will be your final error message.
- Create a new column with all possible error messages by merging all your validation expressions into a huge, hard to mantain and even harder to read, SSIS expression. SSIS syntax isn't the best for theses cases.
- Do your logic in the source of your data, would be in your Oracle database in your case. SQL is much simpler to review and maintain (and usually faster) that SSIS expressions.
- Use a custom script (like VB or C#) to check for conditions and build the error message. It's better than using SSIS expressions but requires a little more programming knowledge.

If you have a reduced number of error validations (lower than 10), then I would suggest doing the first approach. If you are knowledgeable on C#/VB or you can anticipate that you are gonna need a lot of reviewing and maintaining then the last one would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

Try first splitting the data using the conditional split and then use derived column for each error condition. That should help. Also, you could try creating the CASE statement in Oracle and see if that is easier for you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, my problem was with the second part of ur solution ;) all the error suppose to gather and handle in single place.